# Search Bar - filtering numeric value in swift

Tags: swift, searchbar

I am trying to find out how to filter the table view data based on numeric value entered in search bar. for example I have table view with list of persons and want to display persons who are around 20 years of age.....any help would be much appreciated

I could search Numeric values as advised by Rajeev by converting string to double. below is my code.
func filtercontentForSearchText (searchText : String) {

```
    var searchNumber =  NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(searchText)?.doubleValue

  filteredCandies = candies.filter({ (candy : Candy) ->  Bool in


   candy.cal < searchNumber


     })
```

}

It is working for <, == and > filtering. my ultimate aim is to search the data range between 0.9 x of entered value to 1.1 x of entered value. When add any arithmetic operation to searchNumber (say 0.9*searchNumber) I am getting an error "Double? is unwrapped". and if i unwrap it compilation error is going but while running as soon as I touch the search bar the programme exists and it says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Any help on solving this would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you integrated the search bar and search display controller above your table view?

Comment: I have no issues making a search and displaying values by name of the person as it is a String. But not sure how to read the numeric values. No i haven't integrated search display controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved this issue with the following changes. Here is my corrected code

func filtercontentForSearchText (searchText : String ) {

```
    var searchNumber =  NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(searchText)?.doubleValue


if searchNumber != nil {

     filteredCandies = candies.filter({ (candy : Candy) ->  Bool in


   candy.cal >  searchNumber! * 0.9 &&
        candy.cal < searchNumber! * 1.1



     })

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link and add a search bar above your table view

http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift

In the `shouldReloadTableForSearchString` delegate method, you will get the search string that the user has entered. It will also help to enable only the numeric keypad. Convert this to a number and filter out your model into a separate collection. After this, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRows methods, return the values of the collection depending on the table view that is active

Comment: func filtercontentForSearchText (searchText : String) {
    
        var searchNumber =  NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(searchText)?.doubleValue
    
      filteredCandies = candies.filter({ (candy : Candy) ->  Bool in

     
       candy.cal < searchNumber
            
           
         })
   }